# To sum a row string from python dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe

Dataframe was extracted from a CSV file, and is converted into a string through the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

input_csv_file = "./CSV/Officers_and_Shareholders.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(input_csv_file, skiprows=10, on_bad_lines='skip', names= ['Nama', 'Jabatan', 'Alamat', 'Klasifikasi Saham', 'Jumlah Lembar Saham', 'Total'])
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
# df.drop([0, 3], inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Nama', 'Jabatan', 'Alamat', 'Klasifikasi Saham', 'Jumlah Lembar Saham', 'Total']

pattern_shareholding_numbers = re.compile(r'[\d.]*\d+')

shareholding_percentage_list = df["Jumlah Lembar Saham"].astype(str)
shareholding_percentage_thousand_separator_removed = df["Jumlah Lembar Saham"].str.replace('.', '')
shareholding_percentage_string = ' '.join(shareholding_percentage_thousand_separator_removed)
matches = pattern_shareholding_numbers.findall(shareholding_percentage_string)

print(matches)
```

So through the code on the above, an output of the following can be extracted from the CSV file, which looks like the following:

```
['3200000', '2900000', '2900000', '1000000']
```

The numbers shown on the above is a data extracted under the "Jumlah Lembar Saham" column, and the numbers are extracted from different rows within the dataframe. I was wondering if there is a method to add all of the numbers on the above, resulting in one number such as:

```
['10000000']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list like `['3200000', '2900000', '2900000', '1000000']` doesn't contain numbers. It contains text (strings) that represent numbers. A list like `[3200000, 2900000, 2900000, 1000000]` contains numbers.

If you want to sum the numbers represented in a list of strings, you need to turn the strings into numbers, sum those, and then turn the result back into a string, if you need strings in your list.

So:

```
strings = ['3200000', '2900000', '2900000', '1000000']
numbers = list(map(int, strings))
total = sum(numbers)
total_string = str(sum(numbers))
result = [total_string]

print(strings, result)
```

Of course, you can do the whole thing in one step:

```
strings = ['3200000', '2900000', '2900000', '1000000']
result = [str(sum(map(int, strings )))]

print(strings, result)
```

In both cases, the output is:

```
['3200000', '2900000', '2900000', '1000000'] ['10000000']
```

Having said that, since you're using `pandas` with `DataFrame`, you probably want those values to be numbers in the first place, not strings.

There's many ways to skin a cat here, but `pandas` can easily converty a column of strings into numbers, allowing you to sum the result:

```
df['a'].astype(float).sum()
```

This takes column `'a'`, turns the values into floating point numbers, and sums them. Similarly, you could turn an entire `DataFrame` into numbers (`float`, `int`, etc.) or not define the data to be of type `str` to begin with.